# Is there a way to type hint for multiple interfaces in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I've been using Python's ABCs to create interfaces and have a class which implements multiple interfaces, like so:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import override

class InterfaceOne(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> None: ...

class InterfaceTwo(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self) -> None: ...

class Baz(InterfaceOne, InterfaceTwo):

    @override
    def foo(self) -> None: ...

    @override
    def bar(self) -> None: ...
```

I want to type hint a function which will operate on classes which must implement both interfaces. I thought about doing something like below it doesn't appear to be valid syntax.

```py
def do_something(obj: InterfaceOne & InterfaceTwo):
    obj.foo()
    obj.bar()
```

Is anyone aware of any way to do this? From my reading of the documentation, I can only see references to union types, which would be `InterfaceOne | InterfaceTwo`, which would hint to that fact it can accept *either* InterfaceOne or InterfaceTwo, but I would like the function to only accept classes which implement **both**.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using abstract base classes, I find it much more convenient to use Protocols. Protocols can be thought of as a purely abstract base class, where they are limited to just defining attributes/method signatures, or in other words, the shape of the data.

For this example you could define the classes like so:

```
from typing import Protocol


class InterfaceOne(Protocol):
    def foo(self) -> None: ...


class InterfaceTwo(Protocol):
    def bar(self) -> None: ...


class Baz:
    def foo(self) -> None: ...

    def bar(self) -> None: ...
```

You'll notice here that `Baz` itself does not provide a superclass. This is okay. Anywhere you declare you need `InterfaceOne` or `InterfaceTwo`, your preferred type checker should simply check the provided class implements all of the declared methods and attributes... without needing to enforce any class hierarchy!

This (in my opinion) makes these data types much easier to work with and adapt to more use-cases, rather than forcing the definition of all provided inputs to be based off of the one root parent class.

When you want to create a class which implements both `InterfaceOne` and `InterfaceTwo`, you can create a new Protocol which enforces this constraint.

```
class DoSomethingArg(Protocol, InterfaceOne, InterfaceTwo):
    pass


def do_something(obj: DoSomethingArg):
    obj.foo()
    obj.bar()

do_something(Baz())
```

Notice again that we do not need to modify `Baz` at all, while achieving the intersection of interfaces `InterfaceOne & InterfaceTwo`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My solution was to lump all my Protocols into a "typing" module for type hints while continuing to use ABC inheritance to enforce implementations in my concrete classes. However, when I try to use your pattern for multiple interfaces, it doesn't run (at least in 3.12); if `DoSomethingArg` inherits from `Protocol, InterfaceOne, InterfaceTwo`, it errors due to MRO conflicts (makes sense). This is fixed if you omit `Protocol` but then you are no longer allowed to mark it as `@runtime_checkable`. Do you not encounter this issue?

Comment: After playing around with it a bit more, I noticed the MRO conflicts will go away if the inheritance order of is placed so `Protocol` is placed last; so `class DoSomethingArg(InterfaceOne, InterfaceTwo, Protocol)`. You may want to update your answer accordingly.